# Serialize closure without environment

Tags: r, closures

I am serializing objects with the [`serialize`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/serialize.html) function.

For example

```
serialize_object <- serialize(some_object, NULL)
```

Now I have an issue with closures. For example:

```
closure <- function(){
  member <- NULL
  list(init=function(val){member <<- val})
}
closure_serialized <- serialize(closure(), NULL)
```

This raw object `closure_serialized` is huge: some 200MB. I am quite sure that also the environment in which it is made is serialized. But I don't need its environment. I only need the closure and its contents.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I initializing or defining the closure in a wrong way? How can I make it only to serialize the closure and not the rest of the environment? Serializing closures from some packages do not have this effect, and I can not find the culprit.

Comment: I don't have enough confidence in this topic to really answer - but I believe this blog post might be quite helpful to you: http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/03/using-closures-as-objects-in-r/ (especially see section "Problems with R Closures")

Comment: Also make sure to read the comments section

Comment: @HFBrowning, thanks! Clears up a few things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mainly because the definition of the closure is within a function.

```
fn <- function(){

    # make big variables

    closure <- function(){
      member <- NULL
      list(init=function(val){member <<- val})
    }

    closure_serialized <- serialize(closure(), NULL)
}

# serialize will copy the environment within the function in closure_serialized
fn()
```

The `serialize` function will in that case copy the environment also. A "workaround" is to place the definition of the closure in the global environment.

```
closure <- function(){
  member <- NULL
  list(init=function(val){member <<- val})
}

fn <- function(){

    # make big variables

    closure_serialized <- serialize(closure(), NULL)
}

# serialize will not copy the global environment.
fn()
```

The `serialize` doesn't copy `.GlobalEnv` environment. See also [here](https://github.com/mschubert/clustermq/issues/47) for a related topic.